# How do I draw a view exactly like this badge?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

Here it is:

[image]

I want to mimic the glossy gradient, the border and the colour. How is this done with Core Graphics?
Here is how my control looks right now:

[image]

I just need to add this cool border!

Thanks!

Comment: Use bezier path or even you can subclass a textField with implementing drawRect and all.

Comment: Do you have exchanged the graphics: The glossy gradient is on the lower picture, which you describe that is yours. Which one is yours the 212 or the 1000?

Comment: 212 is mine, Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: do you mean the light gray line below the black border line (of icon 1000) : That looks rounded not glossy. Your icon 212 looks glossy